# Getting specific td content

Tags: javascript, html-table

Is it possible to get just one specific td's text from a page?  On the last table I want to get the number of members joined this month so far to use on another page.

Note: It always shows only 12 rows and the current month is the last one.

http://pastebin.com/xGvQMuvp

I don't have access to the page itself or I'd know how to grab this easily by adding an id to that specific `<td>`.

Above is all the code for the page I simply copied from using inspect element. If you scroll to the bottom where it has October 2014 and then 150, I want to get the 150.

It's the 11th table, 14th `<tr>`, 2nd `<td>`.

Comment: It would be better if you could post the full HTML table here, that seems to be a members-only page.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you need to show some code and information

Comment: Do you control that content?

Comment: look into :nth-child() expressions

Comment: @msturdy Edited and added: pastebin.com/xGvQMuvp Sorry I forgot it was only set view-able by members and sadly no I don't have access the the page itself or I'd know how to grab this easily by adding an id to that specific td... Here's all the code for the page I simply copied from using inspect element. If you scroll to the bottom where it has October 2014 and then 150, I wanna get the 150. It's the 11th table, 14th tr, 2nd td.

Comment: @michael I've edited above to include the code, sorry.

Comment: @dandavis Alright is there a way to choose this for a specific table and then a specific td?

Comment: i was hoping to see it in a dom, but if you're numbers are right, then document.getElementsByTagName("table")[10].getElementsByTagName("tr")[13].getElementsByTagName("td")[1] should hit it

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a "userscript".  Different browsers have different ways of letting a user write JavaScript that can do things like inspect a loaded-up web page; you would need to see how your browser lets you do it.  Then, if you are always looking for the same table and the same table row, in a particular page, the task might be relatively easy.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer to what I needed using the nth-child expression like @dandavis suggested to grab the whole page and then show/hide what I needed to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it:

```
//Get <table> number 11
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[10]; 

//Get <tr> number 14
var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[13];

//Get <td> number 2
var td = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

//Get text content
var text = td.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;

console.log(text); // => 150
```